# How to access and handle image file that I have POST-ed to an endpoint? The formData object which I'm sending seem empty

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following function on the front end which makes a POST request to a back end route with a formData object that contains name and image:

```
async createCategory(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", this.category.name)
    formData.append("image", this.category.image)

    let response = await axios.post("/createCategory", formData)
}
```

The function on the back-end, that is meant to access that formData object, shows that the request body is empty. I believe the problem stems from the back-end since I looped over the contents of the formData before POST-ing it, and it all seems dandy.

I've been POST-ing data to my back-end without any problem so far, so I was surprised when my request body turned empty this time. Is there something special I need to do if I'm POST-ing formData object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a library such as [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) for parsing the form data.

```js
const formidable = require("formidable");

const validateMultipartFormData = async (req, res) => {
  const form = formidable({
    uploadDir: "./uploads",
    keepExtensions: true,
    maxFileSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, // 2MB
  });

  const formFields = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);     
      }
      else {
        resolve({ fields, files });
      }    
    });
  });

  // formFields.fields contains data fields
  // formFields.files contains file data (e.g. images)

};
```

Comment: This does not assist solving the root problem. The OP still does not understand HOW to fix the problem.